# How to disable a text field in emberJS when controller loads data

Tags: ember.js

I have the following controller:

```
var ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  search: function(queryString) {
    this.set('model', App.Product.find({query: queryString }));
  }
});
```

and a text field:

```
var SearchFieldView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  insertNewline: function() {
    this.get('controller').search(this.get('value'));
  }
});
```

Now I want to disable the text field when the controller loads a new model in the search function. Using something like `disabledBinding: 'controller.content.isLoaded'` in the view doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  search: function(queryString) {
    this.set('isLoadingData', true);

    var products = App.Product.find({query: queryString });
    this.set('model', products);

    products.then(function() {
      this.set('isLoadingData', false);
    });
  }
});


var SearchFieldView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['disabled'],
  disabledBinding: 'controller.isLoadingData',
  insertNewline: function() {
    this.get('controller').search(this.get('value'));
  }
});
```

### **Explanation**:

Before doing a request set `isLoadingData` to `true`. ember-data `find()` uses the [Promise API](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/22/stabilizing-ember-data.html): Set the `isLoadingData` to `false` when the request has been completed **successfully**. You might want to handle the failed case. See [RSVP.js](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) for reference. Finally bind the disabled property of `Ember.TextField` to `controller.isLoadingData`.

Comment: Seems I have to bind the `then` callback to `this` to get it works. Then it will be just an oneliner: `products.then(this.set.bind(this, 'isLoadingData', false));`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way, as you have already tried:

```
var ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  search: function(queryString) {
    this.set('model', App.Product.find({query: queryString }));
  }
});

var SearchFieldView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['disabled'],
  disabled: function() {
    return this.get('controller.model.isLoaded') === false;
  }.property('controller.model.isLoaded'),
  insertNewline: function() {
    this.get('controller').search(this.get('value'));
  }
});
```

If you want all the Ember.TextField to have the `disabled` property binding:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['disabled']
});
```

Comment: This unfortunately, is disabling the field before before I can type something into it.

Comment: Updated the code: Disable text-field only when `controller.model.isLoaded === false`

Comment: But anyway I think it is best if you use the Promise API. That way you (a) are able to handle failing cases, (b) move the logic into the controller.